# Ternary operation using AVX SIMD

Tags: c++, vectorization, avx

I'm practicing usage with 256bit AVX SIMD instructions and I'm trying to compute the ternary `(a op b) ? x : y`. I have something that quite works, but not really.

EDIT: Code below works. I got a nice speed-up by explicitly vectorizing the ternary operation with this sequence of operations inside a tight loop. Hopefully someone else finds this information useful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <immintrin.h>


int main() {

    float store[8] __attribute__((aligned(32))) = {0}; // data store

    __m256 y = _mm256_set1_ps(10.f); // y = [10,...,10]

    __m256 x = _mm256_set1_ps(100.f); // x = [100,...,100]

    __m256 a = _mm256_set1_ps(0.f); // a = [0,...,0]

    __m256 b = _mm256_setr_ps(0.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 0.f, 1.f, 1.f, 0.f); // b = [0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0]

    __m256 mask1 = _mm256_cmp_ps(a,b, _CMP_LT_OQ); // (a < b ) ? true : false

    // mark1 is now = [false, true, true, true, false, true, true, false]; 

    __m256 res = _mm256_blendv_ps(y,x,mask1); // this operator "blends" the results given the true/false mask
    // 100 if true, 10 if false

    _mm256_store_ps(&store[0], res); // store the results 

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        std::cout << store[i] << std::endl;

    /* prints
    10
    100
    100
    100
    10
    100
    100
    10 */



    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: `_mm256_setr_ps`?

Comment: `blendvps` doesn't change the order. `set_ps` does though, the arguments are weirdly reversed.

Comment: Thanks @MarcGlisse and @harold. I didn't expect that to be the problem. Should this also be an efficient sequence of operations? Pre-compute the arguments `? a : b` and blend `a` and `b` with the mask given by the comparison.

Comment: That's fine in principle but there are often faster ways to calculate something other than blending, depending on the predicate and the operands that are being blended. For example `min` and `max` could be written as a comparison and blend, but shouldn't be.

Comment: @harold If you have an alternative in mind, feel free to post it :)

Comment: Well in this case there's not much to do but blend. The predicate can be calculated simpler since it compares to zero, but maybe that's a placeholder?

Comment: My predicates are compares to zero. How could it be simplified?

Comment: @harold Is there some kind of bit-fiddling trick that can give you the 0-1 mask faster than the comparison function, when we compare against zeros?

Comment: @harold `blendv` instructions will already only consider the sign bit (i.e., the highest bit), so  there is no need to do any `psrad` operations before that.

Comment: If you don't mind treating `-0.0` and `-NaN` as negative, you can use `__m256 b` directly as the blend control, with its sign bits.  Instead of doing `b < 0` as an IEEE FP compare where `-0.0 < 0` is false, as is `-NaN < 0`.  i.e. use `mask1 = b;`.  If your control vector is opposite what you need, swap operands to your blendv instead.